# Dual Monitors with USB 3 to HDMI Adapter

Tags: usb, display, hdmi, adapter

I have an HP Compaq Elite 8300 AIO PC on which I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

Before installing Ubuntu the PC ran Win 10 on which I installed the startech windows device driver from https://www.startech.com/en-nz/display-video-adapters/usb32hdes
This worked whereby the AIO PC monitor and the external monitor showed the desktop.

I then installed U22.04. Afterwards I followed the steps from this link: https://www.startech.com/en-eu/faq/displaylink-install-ubuntu-150-kernel-316
From this link there is a driver to download: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu-5.7?filetype=exe
This is the latest driver and it installed without any errors

However I still am not able to see the option in display settings for a second monitor.

From dmesg I can see the adapter is listed:
[ 2727.300693] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 2735.844096] usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2735.856860] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0711, idProduct=5601, bcdDevice=10.10
[ 2735.856871] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
**[ 2735.856882] usb 4-4: Product: T6 USB Station**
[ 2735.856884] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: MCT Corp.
devbox@thoth-23b017c:~$

and from lsusb the adapter also shows:
devbox@thoth-23b017c:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21f1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Bumble Bee
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0603:8b03 Novatek Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
**Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0711:5601 Magic Control Technology Corp. T6 USB Station**
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bbb:0174 T & A Mobile Phones VFD 620
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0458:0186 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius DX-120 Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
devbox@thoth-23b017c:~$

I thought it might have something to do with the desktop manager sddm so I changed to gdm3 but this also made no difference.

When I run xrandr on both desktop managers only the AIO PC's monitor shows:

devbox@thoth-23b017c:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm

devbox@thoth-23b017c:~$

I am not sure if usb_modeswitch can be used on these adapters but suffice to say I am lost and would appreciate some help.

If anyone has any suggestions or can help resolve this issue I would appreciate it

Thanks in advance
WVW